# Impossible to install MySQL 5.7 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql

This is what I've done so far on a fresh Ububntu 20.04 installation:
`wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb`

In the prompt, I chose Ubuntu Bionic.
In the next prompt, I selected MySQL 5.7 server.
The next prompt selects MySQL5.7 by default. I chose the last option Ok.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server`

```
mysql-server:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
     8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.33-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-5.7 amd64 Packages
```

Than I tried to install the MySQL 5.7.32 server:
`sudo apt-get install -f mysql-client=5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04`

But here is the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '5.7.32-1ubuntu18.04' for 'mysql-server' was not found
```

So what can I do ?
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.7
For client sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.7
Already tested on my lxc container and it's working.